# File Transfer Between 2 EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm planning on transferring a site from one instance to another. Since it's quite a big site, I believe it's better to copy the files from one instance to another directly.

I've followed the instructions found in the 2 links below on how to make sure SCP works:

https://blog.e-zest.com/how-to-do-scp-from-one-ec2-instance-to-another-ec2-instance/
https://blog.microideation.com/2016/05/26/secure-copy-files-scp-between-two-ec2-instances-in-aws/

However, using this command:

```
scp -v test.txt root@x.x.x.x:/home/test_dest.txt
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host x.x.x.x, user root, command scp -v -t /home/test_dest.txt
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 69:bc:99:1d:e8:09:4f:ce:4a:7f:70:45:a3:1f:06:99
debug1: Host 'x.x.x.x' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
lost connection
```

I've checked the Security Group and they're good. File permissions are good as well.

So couple of questions:

1. What does the error above mean? How do I fix it?
2. Is there another way to transfer files between EC2 instances?
3. What else do I need to check to make SCP work?

Comment: What is the OS of the destination machine and its FS?

Comment: @AlexK: according to df, FS is xfs, OS is centos ... on the other hand, source OS is Amazon Linux AMI, while FS is ext4 , I hope that makes sense, I'm not really good with linux

Comment: Can you SSH into that machine? If you can, can you please check if there are differences in the dates of the two machine. The error that bothers me is the Kerberos one.

Comment: Yes I can. I checked and they have the same dates.

Comment: Hmm, can you try rsync rather than scp?

Comment: rsync? I've never tried that before but I will. I will let you know once I've tried it. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexK: I tried rsync, and I got this error: 

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]

Comment: @AlexK: thanks for your help. I've found the issue. Apparently root login is not allowed so I used a non-root user and it worked!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it is working