# how can we copy files from one aws windows instance to another aws windows instance ? my both instances are windows

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to transfer files from one AWS windows instance to another AWS windows instance through a script.
Request you to guide me which script I can use and how can I make a connection between both the instances.

I have tried using pscp but it shows invalid directory on the target destination.

Comment: What do you mean by AWS instance? An EC 2 virtual machine? I’d use ftp, but plenty of people use scp too. Post some more details of your configuration. Like this guy did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523976/file-transfer-between-2-ec2-instances

Comment: As already mentioned in the title, i am talking about AWS windows instance(EC2 windows machine). I want to write a script to copy files from one windows instance to another windows instance.

Comment: @gauravsharma If you had two computers in your own office and you wanted one computer to "send" files to the other computer, which technique would you use? It's probably going to be exactly the same between the Amazon EC2 instances.

Comment: thats what my question is : xcopy and pscp are showing error like invalid destination directory when I am trying to copy between two AWS windows instances.

Comment: @gaurav nowhere in your post mentions EC2. AWS is a vast suite of cloud platform services, you're not being specific as to what part - kinda like if i said "I cant do X in Microsoft Office.." - what is that, Excel? Word? etc. See the link in my comment above; that's a good example of how to ask a question - it has exact commands being used, exact error messages etc. Your question is a bit light on details so we will struggle to help you. Asking a good question here involves giving us good detail on everything you've done, what you're seeing and what you want to see

Comment: @CaiusJard please see this example.                        


C:\Users\Administrator>pscp -pw <TargetInstancePwd> C:\console\Dev-ConsoleApp Administrator@13.231.23.214:C:\console\
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Network error: Connection timed out

C:\Users\Administrator>xcopy C:\console\Dev-ConsoleApp \\13.231.23.214\C$\console
Invalid drive specification
0 File(s) copied